# Tinyproxy: listening and binding on different NICs (eth0, eth1). Routing issues

Tags: networking, network-interface, routing, proxy, http-proxy

[image]

On a Linux server I have 2 NICs: `eth0` and `eth1`.

The server has the IPs:

```
192.168.2.200/24 on eth0 
192.168.3.200/24 on eth1
```

Both the networks have the default subnet mask (`255.255.255.0`) and the default gateway is `192.168.x.254`.

On the server is running tinyproxy with the following configuration.

```
Listen 192.168.2.200
Bind 192.168.3.200
```

The idea is to expose publicly on Internet a proxy where the traffic coming from `eth0` should reach the required resources on Internet via the other interface `eth1`.

It works in LAN only if I put `192.168.3.0` as default route with a lower metric.
But then I can't forward ports anymore from the router on `eth0`, so I can only use the proxy inside my LAN but it's not accessible from outside.

Instead if I put `192.168.2.0` as default route with a lower metric I can access the proxy from the Internet but it's not able to retrieve the resources via the `eth1` interface.

Maybe I need help with routing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in avance.

Comment: "192.168.x.254" - do you mean you have a default gateway on both subnets? "traffic coming from eth0 should reach the required resources" - where is the client? The origin server? "if I put 192.168.3.0 as default route with a lower metric" - a lower metric than what? You shouldn't need to touch your routing when you are setting up proxying. Since you have configured the host to proxy to itself, tinyproxy is adding nothing here.

Comment: @symcbean 

1. Yes, the gateways are 192.168.2.254 and 192.168.3.254.
2. The client is OUTSIDE my LAN somewhere on Internet. 
The origin server is on Internet.
3. I mean the lowest metric (high priority) between default routes.

Comment: eh? If you have 192.168.3.254 as a default gateway you're going to have LOTS of problems. It should ONLY be the gateway for the subnets behind it. And if you tell tinyproxy to *ONLY* connect to 192.168.3.200 then it won't connect to those other servers. Fix your routing (test it from the host) and remove the Bind configuration from tinyproxy.

Comment: @symcbean `Listen` binds the listening socket. `Bind` binds the *local* address for the outgoing *connecting* socket ( http://tinyproxy.github.io/#Bind )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary remarks:

- Parts of the setup below lose network connectivity: this should be done with a direct console access or from a LAN connection to the proxy server, not from arbitrary remote location
- Proper integration with network configuration tools will still have to be done and is not provided here.

---

The current setup with the way the addresses and especially the outgoing socket are used can leverage the use of [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) to reach the goal.

- Anything emitted from 192.168.2.200 uses the "left Internet".
- Anything emitted from 192.168.3.200 uses the "right Internet".
- Anything emitted on a socket not bound (aka bound to INADDR_ANY) leaves the routing decision to the usual default route in the main table. The logical choice would be to also use the "right Internet" since that's also the client part of the proxy server and would make sense to be used by the server itself (eg: packages updates). The rules and routes below are made symmetric so any other choice (including a 3rd gateway on a 3rd interface) will still keep the proxy working as intended.

---

- Starting from scratch by removing any default route(s)

  Requires console or LAN access to avoid loss of connectivity. Of course, commands below should actually be integrated using the network configuration tools and not really flush any route.

  ```
  ip route flush default
  ```
- Add back a "default" default route in the main table

  ```
  ip route add default via 192.168.3.254 dev eth1
  ```
- Prepare alternate default routes symmetrically for both sides

  Using arbitrary routing tables 10000 (left) and 10001 (right). No need to repopulate LAN routes in these tables, the *main* routing table will be kept for these with a rule using a suppressor for the default route (see next bullet).

  ```
  ip route add default via 192.168.2.254 dev eth0 table 10000
  ip route add default via 192.168.3.254 dev eth1 table 10001
  ```
- Add policy rules selecting these routing tables

  Starting with the rule still looking up the main routing table for all non-default routes: LAN routes. A default route result is suppressed from being matched in this rule by `suppress_prefixlength 0`, thus allowing the two next rules to select the proper routing table and thus the proper default route:

  ```
  ip rule add pref 1999 lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0

  ip rule add pref 2000 from 192.168.2.200 lookup 10000
  ip rule add pref 2001 from 192.168.3.200 lookup 10001
  ```

That's all that is needed.

---

As long as *tinyproxy* receives traffic on 192.168.2.200 and emits traffic from 192.168.3.200, each route in both directions will behave as intended:

- Server side of the proxy will receive from and reply to client on eth0

  ```shell
  # ip route get iif eth0 from 192.0.2.2 to 192.168.2.200
  local 192.168.2.200 from 192.0.2.2 dev lo table local 
      cache <local> iif eth0 
  # ip route get from 192.168.2.200 to 192.0.2.2
  192.0.2.2 from 192.168.2.200 via 192.168.2.254 dev eth0 table 10000 uid 0 
      cache
  ```
- Client side of the proxy will send to and get reply from server on eth1

  ```shell
  # ip route get from 192.168.3.200 to 192.0.2.2
  192.0.2.2 from 192.168.3.200 via 192.168.3.254 dev eth1 table 10001 uid 0 
      cache 
  # ip route get iif eth1 from 192.0.2.2 to 192.168.3.200
  local 192.168.3.200 from 192.0.2.2 dev lo table local 
      cache <local> iif eth1
  ```
- Unbound queries will use the main table as usual

  ```shell
  # ip route get to 192.0.2.2
  192.0.2.2 via 192.168.3.254 dev eth1 src 192.168.3.200 uid 0 
      cache
  ```
- Special cases

  For clients on the right LAN side (192.168.3.0/24) or servers on the left LAN side (192.168.2.0/24) possible adaptions might be needed, including on the LAN systems rather than the proxy itself. Should such need arise, this answer can be amended accordingly for such specific case.